# Ввод данных в форму и отображение введенных данных рядом с формой

Tags: jquery, php

Существует такая формула покупки ПРО-аккаунта:

---

```
$day = intval($_POST['day']);
if($day<101)
{
$c = ($day-1) / 50;
$t = $setup['cenapay'] - $c;
$itogo = $day * $t;
}
if($day>=101)
{
$c = 2;
$t = $setup['cenapay'] - $c;
$itogo = $day * $t;
}
```

---

Где `$day` - кол-во дней, `$setup['cenapay']` - цена 1 дня, `$itogo` - итоговая сумма.

```
/* форма */
<input style="cursor: pointer;" type="number" min="1" max="365" name="day" value="10"/>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы без перезагрузки страницы рядом с формой отображалась итоговая сумма.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не заморачиваться с вычислением суммы на сервере и передачей ее браузеру при каждом изменении поля, удобнее передать константу cenapay скрипту, и считать сумму на стороне клиента.

```
<script>
  var cenapay = 10;

  $(window).load(function () {
    $('input[name=day]').change(function () {
      var day = $(this).attr('value');
      var c = 2;
      if (day < 101) {
        c = (day - 1) / 50;
      };
      var itogo = Math.round((cenapay - c) * day);
      $('#price').html(itogo);
    })
  });
</script>

<input style="cursor: pointer;" type="number" min="1" max="365" name="day" value="10" /> Сумма: <span id="price"></span>
```

Comment: Только зачем 

    var day = $(this).attr('value');

Есть же специальный метод .val()

    var day = $(this).val();

И лучше отлавливать событие keyup(), чем change(), т.к. меняться итоговая сумма будет только, когда уберете фокус с поля.

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает.